# How can I get the value of array in only one row in PHP?

Tags: arrays

```
$arr = array('a','b','c');
$v = $arr[1];
//This will return 'b'
```

But I want define the array, get value in only one row, for example:

```
$v = array('a','b','c')[1];
```

But the above code return error. How can I do that?

Comment: Array dereferencing has been improved in recent php versions.  If possible, you might consider simply upgrading past version 5.3.

Comment: [Example in PHP 5.5](https://eval.in/179145)

Comment: My PHP version is 5.4.19, but the above code return this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\test.php on line 2. I will try the 5.5 version. Thanks!